# extracting or separating columns into two different columns

Tags: r

I have a data set of over 72,000 rows and need to extract one column (display_name) into two different columns (county and state) The data in the column looks like "Butler, (AL)" and I need it to separate.

Current Input

```
  cnty_fips display_name               Value
   <chr>     <chr>                      <dbl>
 1 02013     "\"Aleutians East, (AK)\""  125.
 2 02016     "\"Aleutians West, (AK)\""  172.
 3 02020     "\"Anchorage, (AK)\""       336.
 4 02050     "\"Bethel, (AK)\""          478.
```

Desired Output

```
  County          State
   <chr>           <chr>
1 Aleutians East  AL   
2 Aleutians West  AL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tidyr::extract` and specify the regex that you want to extract :

```
tidyr::extract(df, display_name, c('County', 'State'), '(.*),\\s\\((.*)\\)')

#  cnty_fips         County State Value
#1      2013 Aleutians East    AK   125
#2      2016 Aleutians West    AK   172
#3      2020      Anchorage    AK   336
#4      2050         Bethel    AK   478
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(cnty_fips = c(2013L, 2016L, 2020L, 2050L), 
display_name = c("Aleutians East, (AK)", "Aleutians West, (AK)", 
"Anchorage, (AK)", "Bethel, (AK)"), Value = c(125, 172, 336, 478)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you this was exactly what I was looking for! I was having trouble getting the right regex.

Answer (score 2):

We can try using `sub` for a base R option:

```
df$County <- sub(",.*$", "", df$display_name)
df$State <- sub("^.*\\((.*?)\\)$", "\\1", df$display_name)
df

   cnty_fips         display_name Value         County State
1     02013 Aleutians East, (AK)   125 Aleutians East    AK
2     02016 Aleutians West, (AK)   172 Aleutians West    AK
3     02020      Anchorage, (AK)   336      Anchorage    AK
4     02050         Bethel, (AK)   478         Bethel    AK
```

**Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(cnty_fips=c("02013", "02016", "02020", "02050"),
                 display_name=c("Aleutians East, (AK)", "Aleutians West, (AK)",
                                "Anchorage, (AK)", "Bethel, (AK)"),
                 Value=c(125, 172, 336, 478), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```